# An example in implementing libcvm

Tags: python, libsvm

I am implementing SVM with the help of libsvm, and i have installed the package svmutil,libsvm. Still i am getting the error of "svm_problem is not defined".

```
x=[[1,0,1],[-1,0,-1],[1,0,0]]

prob = svm_problem([1,-1,1],x)

param = svm_parameter(kernel_type = LINEAR, C = 10)

m = svm_model(prob, param)

print(m.predict([1,1, 1]))
```

THis is the error message

> name 'svm_problem' is not defined

Comment: Have you imported the module?  (Also, unless you use `from x import y`, you need to refer to functions/classes using their fully-qualified names.)